# minimum total move to balance array if we can increase/decrease a specific array element by 1

Tags: c++, algorithm

It is leetcode 462.
I have one algorithm but it failed some tests while passing others.
I tried to think through but not sure what is the corner case that i overlooked.

We have one array of N elements. One move is defined as increasing OR decreasing one single element of the array by 1. We are trying to find the minimum number of moves to make all elements equal.

My idea is:
1. find the average
2. find the element closest to the average
3. sum together the difference between each element and the element closest to the average.
What am i missing? Please provide one counter example.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int minMoves2(vector<int>& nums) {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            sum += nums[i];
        }
        double avg = (double) sum / nums.size();
        int min = nums[0];
        int index =0 ;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            if(abs(nums[i]-avg) <= abs(min - avg)){
                min = nums[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            sum += abs(min - nums[i]);
        }
        return sum;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the array is [1, 1, 10, 20, 100]. The average is a bit over 20. So your solution would involving 19 + 19 + 10 + 0 + 80 moves = 128. What if we target 10 instead? Then we have 9 + 9 + 0 + 10 + 90 moves = 118. So this is a counter example.

Suppose you decide to target changing all array elements to some value T. The question is, what's the right value for T? Given some value of T, we could ask if increasing or decreasing T by 1 will improve or worsen our outcome. If we decrease T by 1, then all values greater than T need an extra move, and all those below need one move less. That means that if T is above the median, there are more values below it than above, and so we benefit from decreasing T. We can make the opposite argument if T is less than the median. From this we can conclude that the correct value of T is actually the median itself, which my example demonstreates (strictly speaking, when you have an even sized array, T can be anywhere between the two middle elements).

Comment: ok. thanks. I understand now. Setting up a T and analyzing the impact on numbers above it and below it is so such amazing idea.

Comment: Yes, this problem is solvable using binary search.

Comment: @vish4071 I don't see how. All you need is quick select to find the median followed by a single pass. This is all O(N). Binary search implies sorting  which is NlogN.